# Equivalent subgroups of a free group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I recently came across this (somewhat) old MSE question: [If $A^3$ and $B^3$ generate a free group, is $\langle A^3,B^3,(AB)^3,(AB^{-1})^3\rangle$ necessarily free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698754/if-a3-and-b3-generate-a-free-group-is-langle-a3-b3-ab3-ab-13)

And this made me wonder—If $A$ and $B$ generate a free group, is $\langle A^3,B^3\rangle=\langle A^3, B^3, (AB)^3, (AB^{-1})^3\rangle$? My intuition tells me no, but I am not able to prove this. Are they the same?

Comment: No; they don’t even have the same normal closure. If $N$ is the normal closure of $\langle A^3,B^3\rangle$, then $F/N$ maps onto $C_3*C_3$, where $AB$ has infinite order. So $(AB)^3\notin N$.

Comment: The generalised word problem is soluble for free groups, and is applicable here and in more general questions of this form (as it shows that $(AB)^3\not\in\langle A, B\rangle$ here). Look up "Stallings' foldings" for an easy, "visual" (automata-like) solution to this problem.